# popup box in bootstrap not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout where on a click of a button a box should appear and on click of the same link the box should disappear

My complete code is here at [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learner001/s8dvqs1z/2/)

The problem is that after opening the box on a click of a link, i change the content inside it by clicking on login/register, after that i am not able to close the box by clicking on the Main Link again, can anyone tell how it can be done

HTML CODE

```
<a href="#" class="login" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#demo"><b>Main Link</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <div id="demo" class="dropdown">
        <ul id="loginbtn" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <form>
                    Login form
                </form>
                <a href="#" id="register">Register</a>  
            </li>
        </ul> 

        <ul id="signupbtn" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <form>
                    Register form
                </form>

                <a href="#" id="login">Login</a>        
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#signupbtn
{
  display:none;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#register").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loginbtn').hide(); 
            $('#signupbtn').show();
            return false;
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loginbtn').show(); 
            $('#signupbtn').hide();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your JsFiddle is working fine for me

Comment: I'm with Chrome, when dropdown is open and click on register to swicth dropdown menu, I can't close it on clicking outside too.

Comment: @Pirate X it works only once, but i click inside the box then it won't get closed

Answer (score 0):

One way should be with the use of hidden class instead.

**JsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/p1a0v6kj/

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" class="login" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#demo"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <div id="demo" class="dropdown">
        <ul id="loginbtn" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <form>
                    Login form
                </form>
                <a href="#" id="register">Register</a>  
            </li>
        </ul> 

        <ul id="signupbtn" class="dropdown-menu hidden">
            <li>
                <form>
                    Register form
                </form>

                <a href="#" id="login">Login</a>        
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Js**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#register").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loginbtn').addClass('hidden'); 
            $('#signupbtn').removeClass('hidden');
            return false;
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loginbtn').removeClass('hidden'); 
            $('#signupbtn').addClass('hidden');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Now the box is clsing but has caused another issue, for the first time when i click on the link the css inside the box is getting disturbed. i.e for the first time, the 2 layouts both are visible and overlapping each other, and the second form is getting displayed on top and first form is in the background

Comment: id="signupbtn" must have class hidden at init